# Pause Voiceover when recording audio

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

I am transcribing speech to text.When Accessibility VoiceOver is on,it is recording voiceOver voice also.How can i pause voiceover while recording.
I can see in apple keyboard (microphone button),they did a similar thing.

I tried to post notifications for pauseAssistivetechnology but it is crashing.

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try audioSession.setActive(true, options: 
 .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
try 
 audioSession.setCategory(.record,mode:.default)
```

I am using above code to pause voiceover when microphone is on as pauseAssistiveTechnology is not working.

But that is not smooth.I want to make it same like the default apple microphone when we switch on the accessibility,the voice of focus only comes until microphone is on.

How I can I achieve that?Please help.Stuck for over 15 days.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "I can see in apple keyboard (microphone button),they did a similar thing." But "they" is Apple. Apple can do things you can't do. This might not be possible.